# Loop inline python code causing a syntax bug

Tags: python, list

i'm learning how to write inline code right now i came across this problem

> Write an inline `for loop` in python to remove all the **numbers & capital** letters from this list of codes and return a clean list.
> `Ex1: input_list = ['1aGpple', '2Uboy', '3cat4', '5li3on3']`
> output: `['apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'lion']`

**try 1**

```
a=['1aGpple', '2Uboy', '3cat4', '5li3on3']


t=[c for c in [a[i] for i in range(len(a))] if c.isupper()]
print(str(t))
```

**try 2**

```
a=['1aGpple', '2Uboy', '3cat4', '5li3on3']


t=[ a[i] for i in range(len(a))&&c for c in a[i] if c.isupper()]
```

if you have good documentation to write inline code please provide me

Comment: Here you have the official documentation for list comprehensions https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: `&&` is not a thing in Python.

Comment: It looks like you are asking about two separate issues – writing a comprehension ("inline loop") to handle many strings and removing all but lowercase letters from one string. Which if these two are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by splitting the problem in to pieces

```
words = ['1aGpple', '2Uboy', '3cat4', '5li3on3']
```

First, iterate the list of strings

```
for word in words
```

Now, iterate each and every character of the word

```
for char in word
```

Now reconstruct the list of characters by excluding digits and capital letters

```
[char for char in word if not char.isupper() and not char.isdigit()]
```

This just gives a list of characters, so you have to join them together

```
"".join([char for char in word if not char.isupper() and not char.isdigit()])
```

Now, put them all together

```
[
    "".join([c for c in word if not c.isupper() and not c.isdigit()])
    for word in words
]
```

which would produce

```
['apple', 'boy', 'cat', 'lion']
```